# "Application" button doesn't work

Tags: applications

After update on my laptop it's not working. Today I updated my desktop - it doesn't too. Anybody having the same problem?

Answer (score -3):

Run `pkill slingshot` in the terminal then run `gnome-session-properties` and add the command to startup applications

Comment: Which command should be added?

Comment: pkill slingshot - in startup